# How to refresh date time when the app is reactivated in WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, datetime, tombstoning

i would like to know if it is possible to refresh date time when the app returns from a deactivated state in WP7.5. My app is basically a calendar type and when the app starts the current day is highlighted.

So if i start the app, then press the start button, my app goes to deactivated state, then go to settings and change the time zone, naturally the date and time may change and then come back to my app, it retains the old date.

eg.
Suppose current date is 20 and we change the timezone where the date is 19, ideally my app should highlight 19, but it does not. I assume that its becomes before the app goes into deactivated state, it stores all the states and when it returns, it loads the same data. Is there anyway i could refresh the datetime?

Alfah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a model class that contains a DateTime field called `DateToDisplayAsToday`, and that model is accessible within App.XAML, you will want to to the following in App.xaml.cs

```
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Application_Launching fires when the app starts up.

        // retrieve any data you persisted the last time the app exited.

        // Assumes you have a local instance of your model class called model.
        model = new model(); 
    }

    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Application_Activated fires when you return to the foreground.
        // retrieve any data you persisted in the Application_Deactivated
        // and then you can set the current DateTime
        model.DateToDisplayAsToday = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // persist an data you don't want to lose during tombstoning
    }

    private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // persist any data you want to keep between separate executions of the app
    }
```

Comment: Apparently I found out that even by changing the timezones it does not get reflected when the app is reactivated. I had checked the TimeZoneInfo.local. It holds the same time even after changing. :(

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I've done any WP7 development, but I'm sure there's an event raised when the app is reactivated - can't you just query `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.Today` at that point?

EDIT: Looking at the docs, I think you want the [Launching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.launching%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.activated%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) events. (`Launching` so that you check the time even on the initial launch; `Activated` for reactivation after becoming dormant.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. The problem is that DateTime.Today always returns the date when the app was started the first time around(If the app is deactivated). Unless the app is exit and started again, DateTime.Now and DateTime.Today returns the old date.

Comment: @alfah: That sounds very strange to me - if you use `DateTime.Now` it should *always* give you the current time. I'm sure it's not just giving you "the original time" - it *may* not have noticed the time zone change, admittedly... to diagnose that, check `TimeZoneInfo.Local` before and afterwards... if that *is* changing, you may be able to just use `DateTime.UtcNow` along with `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.

Comment: if (dateToDisplay == System.DateTime.Now.Day && m_monthBuffer[i, j] == m_selectedDate.Month)
 {//do somthing} I have used this condition and System.DateTime.Now gives a me 20th jan instead of 19th Jan when i have changed the timezone while the app is in deactivated state. .
                            }

Comment: @alfah: So have you checked what `TimeZoneInfo.Local` gives you before and afterwards, as I suggested?

Comment: Yep I did check the TimeZoneInfo.Local and apparently even though the timezones are changed in the settings, it is not getting relected here.. It holds the same zone as the first one even after changing. So any means to refresh that??

Comment: Oh. . Everytime the app has to be exited i guess :( Anyway Thanks :)